# Movies lag in full screen, although flash works fine

Tags: video, flash, multimedia, mp4

I have an Alienware m11x R2 computer running Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) with Nvidia drivers and Bumblebee for Optimus technology.

The problem that I have is that if I play a video in full screen it lags, not really bad but enough to notice the lag and for me to get get frustrated. However, flash works fine; my problem lies with mp4, mkv, and other formats like these.

I have tried the default Ubuntu applications and others and they all have the same problems with video playback.

Everything works fine on Ubuntu except this and I don't know how I can fix this.

This is how I installed Bumblebee and Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable 
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How is video playback with Miro?

Comment: It is exactly the same. I don't think it is a problem with the media players. I am quite sure I did not to something as I should.   Do I need to install intel drivers to, if i have used the code above to install bumblebee???

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same problem, although I have a AMD HD5870 (with catalyst control panel) and a 32-bit system (Ubuntu 12.04).

I already disabled Sync to VBlank in Compiz config manager, but this did not do anything for my lag.

EDIT

After re-enabling the Sync to Vblank in compiz-config and logging out and in, the video playback was great. I suggest you try the same.